# Spring boot application not accepting ID of incoming POST request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an existing system that uses string based unique IDs for users and I want to transfer that System into a Spring boot application. I want to creat a user so I send a POST request with the following content:

[image]

As you can see, the id gets ignored.
This is my Spring code for the user class:

```
@PostMapping("/user")
    ResponseEntity addUser(User receivedUser) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
        logger.info("Empfangener User: " + receivedUser.toString());
        try {
            User mailCheckUser = userService.getUserByMail(receivedUser.getEmail());
            User nameCheckUser = userService.getUserByName(receivedUser.getUsername());

            if (mailCheckUser != null){
                return new ResponseEntity("Email already exists", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
            }
            if (nameCheckUser != null){
                return new ResponseEntity("Username already exists", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
            }
            userService.addUser(receivedUser);
        } catch (Exception userCreationError) {
            return new ResponseEntity(receivedUser, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(receivedUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


public void addUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

And this is my user class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(unique =true)
    private String id;
    private @Column(unique =true)
    String username;
    private  @Column(unique =true)
    String email;
    private  @Column(unique =true)
    String simpleAuthToken;
    private
    String password;
    /*REDACTED*/
    private
    boolean isBlocked;

    public User(String id, String name, String email, boolean isBlocked) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.simpleAuthToken = simpleAuthToken;
        this.isBlocked = false;
    }

    public User() {

    }
    /*GETTERS AND SETTERS ARE HERE, BUT I CUT THEM FOR SPACING REASONS*/
}
```

And this is the Spring Output:
[image]

My expected outcome would be that Spring would recognize the id and then create a user with the id  I provided. Why is the id always null?

EDIT: If I put the ID in a Put or Get Mapping as Path variable, like so:

```
@PutMapping("/user/{id}")
ResponseEntity updateUser(@PathVariable String id, User receivedUser) {}
```

then it gets read and recognized, but it will still be null in the `receivedUser`

Comment: Have you tried dropping a breakpoint in both `User` constructors and `setId` to see how spring is constructing the entity? I'd have assumed it would be calling the no args constructor and setters.

Comment: Just did that and spring indeed uses the empty constructor. That leaves me wondering how the username gets its way into the user. Is there a way to force spring to use the args constructor?

Comment: I think it's constructing an empty object using the no-args constructor and then using the setters. Have you dropped a breakpoint into setUsername and setId? The question for me is what's going wrong in setId.

Comment: I am not setting username or ID, because all my userService.addUser is doing is saving the user to the repository (And it works, but the id being null is the issue).
After deleting the no args constructor, the id gets read correctly, but I still get an internal server error. I am currently investigating

Comment: I forgot that removing the defaul constructor leads to exceptions when sending a GET request. As you can see, my constructor already sets up some values but it does not get used. Do you have an Idea why this happens?

Comment: I can't really tell without having the code to hand. However, I wouldn't expect to see the JPA entity feature in the controller. I'd expect to see a DTO object with the fields you need to use in the controller, that's then passed to the service layer which will perform all business logic, map the DTO to the JPA entity and handle transactions etc. Having a "live" JPA entity in the controller is poor separation of concerns. I.E. `ResponseEntity addUser(UserDTO receivedUser)` Hope this helps.

Comment: You do not need setters on your model members that do not need changing, especially not id's. Also, simpleAuthToken isn't a param in your constructor, and isBlocked is a param in your constructor that isn't used. For your problem: I don't think the incomming formdata is automatically parsed to a User object, just because you set the parameter type to User.

Comment: User seems to be parsed at least partly, since the username (in this case an email address) gets parsed fine. I will test a bit with what gets parsed and what not. I think I have a pretty good idea through this conversation. If I have a solution, I will share it

Comment: I added the id to the params the post method is receiving and it gets parsed. I then set the users ID to the received one and save the user (The ID is safely unique, so I can do this)

Answer (score 0):

First add `@RequestBody` in the post request body. In the Post request (`/test/user`) your passing some params but in the method level not received.

If you want receive id from postman then add `@RequestParam("id")String id` in the method level.

How you generating unique Id by manually or some generators?
And double check user id at the database console level.

Comment: Each id is uniquely generated by another system, hence the using that for identification. Using the @BodyRequest tag throws the error ``Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' not supported]`` on Requesting something